# Deploy an LLM (pretrained Llama2) from local to pythonanywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere, large-language-model

I have been exploring LLMs for a few months now; It is very interesting to be able to run open-source models locally. I wonder if anyone here has successfully hosted one on pythonanywhere and how they did it!

Kindly, Thanks.

What I am trying --> langchain